# Горячие клавиши в Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

есть ли возможность создавать свои сочетания горячих клавиш в Idea, если да, то как?

Comment: Я конечно все понимаю, но SO - это не гугл. Ваш вопрос было бы легко найти в поисковой системе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, вы можете добавлять свои сочетания клавиш на любые действия, и переназначать существующие. Для этого зайдите в **Settings** -> **Keymap**